# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> in servlet mapping

Tags: tomcat, servlets, web.xml, illegalargumentexception, servlet-mapping

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>workflow.WDispatcher</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*NEXTEVENT*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Above is the snippet from Tomcat's `web.xml`. The URL pattern `*NEXTEVENT*` on start up throws

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> in servlet mapping

It will be greatly appreciated if someone can hint at the error.
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Answer (score 103, accepted):

```
<url-pattern>*NEXTEVENT*</url-pattern>
```

The URL pattern is not valid. It can either end in an asterisk or start with one (to denote a file extension mapping).

The url-pattern specification:

> - A string beginning with a ‘/’ character and ending with a ‘/*’
>     suffix is used for path mapping.
> - A string beginning with a ‘*.’ prefix is used as an extension
>     mapping.
> - A string containing only the ’/’ character indicates the "default"
>     servlet of the application. In this
>     case the servlet path is the request
>     URI minus the context path and the
>     path info is null.
> - All other strings are used for exact matches only.

See section 12.2 of the [Java Servlet Specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr340/index.html) Version 3.1 for more details.

Comment: Here is a nice explanation of servlet mappings: http://javapapers.com/servlet/what-is-servlet-mapping/

Answer (score 1):

A workaround that can achieve that is to add a servlet filter to do URL re-writes e.g.
re-write *NEXTEVENT* to /NEXTEVENT/*(the one before the NEXTEVENT)/*(the one after NEXTEVENT) or something similar.