# URL Pattern for servlet mapping in web.xml

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, web.xml

I need a workaround with this URL mapping in web.xml to create URLs with a letter, followed by a "_" followed by any combination of alphanumeric characters.

I want to map a servlet to something like this:

```
/something_*
```

Instead of:

```
/something/*
```

Using different "somethings" for different JSP's. Example:

```
/search_Something-I-searched-for
```

I tried using:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/something_*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

But this doesn't seem to work.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732/invalid-url-pattern-servlet-mapping-in-tomcat-6-0) tells me I can't do this within web.xml, so maybe there's some workaround.

I don't know if this information is important, but I'm using JBoss and Struts2 in my project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Map a servlet to the containing directory. Inside that servlet, take apart the URL path and [forward](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) to the appropriate [named servlet](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getNamedDispatcher%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

Why not try Spring MVC Framework. Spring can offer that url mapping you want.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/something_{name}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String demo(@PathVariable(value="name") String name, ModelMap map) {

String something = name;

// Do manipulation

return "something"; // Forward to something.jsp
}
```

Watch this [Spring MVC Framework Tutorial](http://youtu.be/Q6hZQ5SzGyM)