# mapping of url in web.xml for java servlet

Tags: java, servlets, web.xml, url-mapping

I read this - [url mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491773/url-pattern-for-servlet-mapping-in-web-xml) in stackoverflow.
I am new to java web, and trying to map the url in web.xml for company detail page... I have following lines in web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CompanyController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin/companies.html</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/admin/company/add</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/admin/company/edit</url-pattern>
    // error in this url
    <url-pattern>/admin/*/company-details.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Concept of this mapping is /admin/{id_of_company}/company-details.html, returns `HTTP status 404 - Not Found`, is there anyway to make it workable using web.xml only, or should I move  to [url mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491773/url-pattern-for-servlet-mapping-in-web-xml)

Comment: <servlet>
    <servlet-name>servletname</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servletJavaClassName</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

Comment: servelt class is mapped in other

Comment: could you please update it ??

Comment: You should probably look for documentation of the web.xml (deployment descriptor) like [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13712/web_xml.htm#WBAPP502)