# Is it possible to use wildcards within J2EE - fitlers?

Tags: tomcat, servlet-filters

I would like to apply a filter to severl url endings. The next configuraiton seems to work.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>LanguageFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>filters.LanguageFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LanguageFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LanguageFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xml</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Originally I asked if it was possible to use wildcards such as:

```
    <url-pattern>*.do|*.xml</url-pattern>
```

But it does not seem to be possible.

Answer (score 2):

There is no notion of such an operator in the standard, so you need two mappings. The specification of the mappings is available in the servlet specification. See [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732/invalid-url-pattern-servlet-mapping-in-tomcat-6-0) for a link and section.

Answer (score 0):

You could cheat a bit, and map /*.* to your filter class, then have your Filter Implementation take a parameter where *.do|*.xml are parsed and though your filter, technically is able to see too much, it does a simply check on whether or not you've given it an additional test, does the test, and either filter's or noops.