# How do I use wild cards (*) in url-pattern with MVC correctly

Tags: java, model-view-controller, url-pattern, deployment-descriptor

I am trying to get a servlet to respond to every request with a url-pattern of "/test/*". so this controller should respond to :

```
myApp/test/
myApp/test/whatever
myApp/somehting?other=stuff
```

using the following mapping:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The controller is called fine but the forwarding to the view:

```
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("test.jsp");
view.forward(request,response);
```

is generating an error:

Exceeded maximum depth for nested request dispatches

I guess the url matching happens on forwards to views too? as in it is going through the same routing process as incoming requests - or partly?

what is the correct way to use * in the url-pattern without causing this?

Comment: Try this link, it explains what you can really do in the <url-pattern/> tag: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732/invalid-url-pattern-servlet-mapping-in-tomcat-6-0/26744

Comment: thanks, thats what I thought (* at the start or end) and like I say its hitting the controller.

Comment: It seems that adding "../" to the front of the file name in the line creating the view "fixed" it. I am not convinced this is the right thing to do though.

Comment: I think potentially the answer here is to use an absolute reference to the file? maybe the routing behaviour is a fall back?