# Is there a regular expression based servlet filter for web.xml?

Tags: java, spring, guice, servlet-filters, web.xml

I am in the process of migrating some code from Guice to Spring. guice-servlet has the nice feature that allows you to match servlet filters using regular expressions. For example I am using

```
filterRegex("^.*\\.cache\\..*$").through(ForceCacheFilter.class);
```

I need to replicate this in Spring.

I could easily write a filter that takes a regular expression and the class name of a filter to delegate to as a parameter/attribute. It would match the URL against the regexp and delegate to the filter class if required. I guess this could be taken further and have a filter that dispatches to multiple filters based on regexps - just like what Guice is doing.

What I am surprised about is that I haven't been able to find something that does this already. Maybe I haven't looked hard enough or maybe its not such a good idea?

Does something like this exist or do I need to write some code?

Comment: Found this on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570805/can-we-user-regular-expression-type-patterns-in-web-xml
Seems like it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using Spring-MVC?

Answer (score -2):

do you mean something like?

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>someFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.SomeFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>someFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/somePath/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: This should have been a comment rather than being an answer.