# About Filter to check your authority

Tags: java, servlets, filter

For example : I have some jsp pages. But I just want to let my filter work one some of them.
How could I config to make it ?
Thanks! I troubled me for all day!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to put the JSP pages on diferent directories, than in your web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>FilterName1</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.example.Filter1</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>FilterName1</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/directory-for-filter-1/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>FilterName2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.example.Filter2</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>FilterName2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/directory-for-filter-2/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Also take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570805/can-we-user-regular-expression-type-patterns-in-web-xml