# Java Servlet - Redirect URL

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters, google-crawlers, hashbang

The URLs of my website are `www.example.com/?id=THEPRODUCTID#i` where `THEPRODUCTID` is an alphanumeric string. Please note that #i is present at the end.

The problem is that Google crawlers are ignoring the `#i` specified on `Sitemap.xml`, so the results I can see on Google are `www.example.com/?id=THEPRODUCTID`.

As a quick solution, I want to create a servlet that redirects `www.example.com/?id=THEPRODUCTID` to `www.example.com/?id=THEPRODUCTID#i`. I am not sure how to do the mapping, or if it should be a filter, redirect, forward,... any guidance is very much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you relying on the optional [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)?

Comment: I am using GWT and I use it to load the viewer (#i), the edit (#e), etc. I really cannot change it.

Comment: In GWT `#` is used as history token.

Comment: Can you check if it isn't present, and default to viewer.

Comment: Are you using GWT history in the project?

Comment: Elliot, if #i is not present, I get a GWT error. Braj, this is not GWT history. It is for the same purpose as hash bang. Actually I have the same problem if I try to crawl www.example.com/?id=THEPRODUCTID#!v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into url rewriting, for instance with [Tuckey](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/), and you can get rid of this whole procedure for your external urls, and keep it on the backend.

You can create rules to have your url be like `www.example.com/product/THEPRODUCTID/i` on the user end and get translated to `www.example.com/?id=THEPRODUCTID#i` in the backend.

Comment: Thanks! I am trying it but seems that it does not work properly, perhaps the '?' in the 'to'?
`<urlrewrite>
   <rule>
    <from>/i/([a-zA-Z]+)</from>
    <to>/?id=$1#i</to>
   </rule>
</urlrewrite>`

Comment: In the `to`, try with your servlet or JSP that responds as the welcomefile explicit: e.g. `<to>/index.jsp?id=$1#i</to>`

Answer (score 1):

Everything that comes after # is called fragment and is intended to serve as a bookmark for a browser. The content that is served by the server for www.example.com/?id=THEPRODUCTID#i and www.example.com/?id=THEPRODUCTID will be absolutely the same.

If you build redirect functionality as you've suggested all requests to ww.example.com/?id=THEPRODUCTID will be redirected, not only the links generated by Google. If you're OK with that, use the following to redirect inside the servlet

```
response.sendRedirect("/id=THEPRODUCTID#i?);
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried the below but Servlet is never called with `www.example.com/?id=asdfasdf`. Perhaps due to the regex?
`<servlet>
     <servlet-name>RedirectServlet</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>com.a.m.server.RedirectServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>RedirectServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/?id=([a-zA-Z]+)</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>`

Comment: serlet-mapping content is not exactly a traditional regexp. Take a look at this link to understand what's allowed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8570805/can-we-user-regular-expression-type-patterns-in-web-xml