# Spring Filter URL pattern not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am registering a filter as shown below -

```
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean jwtFilter() {
        final FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registrationBean.setFilter(new AuthenticationFilter());
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/secure/*");
        registrationBean.setOrder(1);

        return registrationBean;
    }
```

When i use the following url this filter works -

> localhost:8080/secure/getUsers

But does not work for the below url -

> localhost:8080/skeleton-service/secure/getUsers

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("secure/*","skeleton-service/*");
```

Comment: is there a wildcard that i can specify before /secure, which means that any url preceding /secure should also be included?

Comment: @sijojosan There is no way in Servlet Specification to use regexp or some pattern matching. Rules are pretty simple. take a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/8571248/1032167

Comment: Better good pattern is you have to bring it under same root pattern .like under " /secure/*"