# Java - Setting filter in web.xml returns error A child container failed during start

Tags: java, apache, servlets, filter

I just started developing my first web application using Dynamic Web Project 3.0 and I encounter the following error when I 
 try to start the apache tomcat 7.0 server with the filter tag in Web.xml file.

The error displayed:

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:     
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) 
at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase. 
startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.
startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core. 
ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.
ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor 
.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$
  Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624 
 )at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My Filter class:

```
  public class LoginPageFilter implements Filter {
                public LoginPageFilter() { }
                public void destroy() { }
                public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, 
    ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, 
    ServletException {
                    System.out.println("LoginPageFilter pass before Call 
    of LoginPageController!");
                    chain.doFilter(request, response);
                }
                public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws 
ServletException { }
}
```

Web.xml file:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>LoginPageFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.licenta.servletFIlters.LoginPageFilter</filter- 
    class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>LoginPageFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*lContr</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Sorry for the crappy format, first time asking a question on StackOverflow.

Thank you guys in advance,
Kind regards,
Armand Gabriel

Comment: WEB.xml :<filter>
   <filter-name>LoginPageFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>com.licenta.servletFIlters.LoginPageFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>LoginPageFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>*lContr</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

Comment: Do not clarify question by adding "code" in a comment. **Edit** the question. Delete the comment.

Comment: The reason for child container failure is likely shown right above or below the error, so have another look at the log output.

Comment: Show the full source code of `LoginPageFilter`, including `package` and `import` statements. And please format all of it correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we use regular expressions in web.xml URL patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8570805/5221149). --- `<url-pattern>*lContr</url-pattern>` is not a valid pattern.

Comment: Thank you guys, The problem was that i was missing backquote at <url-pattern> so instead of <url-pattern>*lContr</url-pattern> it should be <url-pattern>/*lContr</url-patter> Cheers!