# ColdFusion 10 does not work for Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: coldfusion, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, coldfusion-10

I'm trying to deploy ColdFusion 10 to the AWS ElasticBeanstalk service but the stock configuration is failing. I'm trying to create a x64 Tomcat 6 environment.

Do you know what changes need to be made to allow ColdFusion 10 to be deployed via Amazone Elastic Beanstalk while permitting the stock config such as SES links? Thanks!

**Exception**

```
    SEVERE: Parse error in application web.xml file at jndi:/localhost/WEB-INF/web.xml
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: jndi:/localhost/WEB-INF/web.xml; lineNumber: 500; columnNumber: 23; Error at (500, 23: Invalid <url-pattern> *.cfml/* in servlet mapping
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2806)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2832)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.endElement(Digester.java:1141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:604)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endNamespaceScope(XMLDTDValidator.java:2102)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleEndElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:2053)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.endElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:927)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1759)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2915)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:625)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:819)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:748)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1208)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:525)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1642)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationWebConfig(ContextConfig.java:365)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.start(ContextConfig.java:1076)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4612)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
```

...

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app id="adobe_coldfusion">
    <display-name>WARTest</display-name>
    <description>Adobe ColdFusion 10</description>
    <context-param id="coldfusion_context_1">
        <param-name>cftags</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/cftags</param-value>
        <description>Path to search for built-in tags. Relative to application root.
            This parameter can only be one path element.</description>
    </context-param>
    <context-param id="coldfusion_context_2">
        <param-name>coldfusion.compiler.outputDir</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/cfclasses</param-value>
        <description>This is the directory where we will place compiled
            pages. It must be relative to the webapp root.</description>
    </context-param>
    <context-param id="coldfusion_context_4">
        <param-name>cfx.registry.nativelibrary</param-name>
        <param-value>cfregistry</param-value>
        <description>Native library that implements CFX_REGISTRY.
            Used on Windows only.</description>
    </context-param>
    <context-param id="coldfusion_context_5">
        <param-name>cfx.report.nativelibrary</param-name>
        <param-value>cfreport</param-value>
        <description>Native library that implements CFX_REPORT.
            Used on Windows only.</description>
    </context-param>
    <context-param id="coldfusion_context_88">
        <param-name>cf.class.path</param-name>
        <param-value>
            ./WEB-INF/../../../classes,./WEB-INF/../../lib/updates,./WEB-INF/../../lib,./WEB-INF/flex/jars,./WEB-INF/cfform/jars,./WEB-INF/../../lib/axis2</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param id="coldfusion_context_89">
        <param-name>cf.lib.path</param-name>
        <param-value>./WEB-INF/../../lib</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- CF Monitoring Filter  -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CFMonitoringFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>filter.class</param-name>
            <param-value>coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <!-- Cache Filter for cfform swfs -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CFCacheFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>filter.class</param-name>
            <param-value>flex.server.j2ee.cache.CacheFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <!-- Request Control Filter for Flash Remoting servlets-->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>FlashRemotingControlFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>filter.class</param-name>
            <param-value>coldfusion.filter.FlashRequestControlFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <!-- WSRP portlet Filter for wsrp producer -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>WSRPFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>filter.class</param-name>
            <param-value>coldfusion.portlet.wsrp.ProviderImpl</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <!-- CF ClickJacking deny protection Filter  -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CFClickJackFilterDeny</filter-name>
        <filter-class>coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>filter.class</param-name>
            <param-value>coldfusion.filter.ClickjackingProtectionFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>mode</param-name>
            <param-value>DENY</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <!-- CF ClickJacking same origiin protection Filter  -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CFClickJackFilterSameOrigin</filter-name>
        <filter-class>coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>filter.class</param-name>
            <param-value>coldfusion.filter.ClickjackingProtectionFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>mode</param-name>
            <param-value>SAMEORIGIN</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <!-- CF ClickJacking Filter mapppings starts. For ColdFusion Administrator we are allowing sameorigiin frames. Use Deny or some other mode of this filter as appropriate for the application and add required url pattern
    -->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CFClickJackFilterSameOrigin</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/CFIDE/administrator/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!-- End CF ClickJacking Filter mappings -->

    <!-- CF Monitoring Filter mappings
     When new servlets registered in web.xml, it must be ensured that
     filter mappings are added for this filter as required.
     Note that the MessageBrokerServlet for the Flex 2 Gateway is not
     included here. This is because Flex appears to batch invocations
     for methods invoked close to one another, resulting in the filter
     being missed for all batched invocations other than the first.
    -->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CFMonitoringFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>FlashGateway</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CFMonitoringFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>CFFormGateway</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CFMonitoringFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>CfmServlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CFMonitoringFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>CFCServlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CFMonitoringFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>CFRestServlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!-- End CF Monitoring Filter mappings -->

    <!-- Request Control Filter for Flash Remoting servlets -->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>FlashRemotingControlFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>MessageBrokerServlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>FlashRemotingControlFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>FlashGateway</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
    <!-- end request control filters -->

    <!-- Cache Filter for cfform swfs -->
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>CFCacheFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>CFSwfServlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

   <!-- WSRP portlet Filter for wsrp producer -->
   <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>WSRPFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>WSRPProducer</servlet-name>
   </filter-mapping>    


    <listener>
        <listener-class>coldfusion.bootstrap.HttpFlexSessionBootstrap</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Message Broker Servlet, wrapped in a ColdFusion specific class -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MessageBrokerServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>servlet.class</param-name>
            <param-value>coldfusion.flex.ColdFusionMessageBrokerServlet</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>services.configuration.file</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/flex/services-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>11</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CFSwfServlet</servlet-name>
        <display-name>SWF Retreiver</display-name>
        <servlet-class>coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>servlet.class</param-name>
            <param-value>flex.server.j2ee.SwfServlet</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>5</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CFMxmlServlet</servlet-name>
        <display-name>MXML Processor</display-name>
        <description>Servlet wrapper for the Mxml Compiler</description>
        <servlet-class>coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>servlet.class</param-name>
            <param-value>flex.compiler.MxmlServlet</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CFForbiddenServlet</servlet-name>
        <display-name>Prevents access to *.as files</display-name>
        <servlet-class>coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>servlet.class</param-name>
            <param-value>flex.server.j2ee.ForbiddenServlet</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <!-- end flash forms settings -->

    <servlet id="coldfusion_servlet_1">
        <servlet-name>ColdFusionStartUpServlet</servlet-name>
        <display-name>Coldfusion MX Startup Servlet</display-name>
        <description>Initializes ColdFusion</description>
        <servlet-class>coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param id="InitParam_1034013110641">
            <param-name>servlet.class</param-name>
            <param-value>coldfusion.server.j2ee.CFStartUpServlet</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param id="InitParam_1034013110642">
            <param-name>cfRootDir</param-name>
            <param-value>./WEB-INF/cfusion</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param id="InitParam_1034013110643">
            <param-name>appServer</param-name>
            <param-value>J2EE</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet id="coldfusion_servlet_11">
        <servlet-name>FlashGateway</servlet-name>
        <display-name>Flash Gateway</display-name>
        <description>Allows flash to connect to CFML and CFC templates.</description>
        <servlet-class>coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param id="InitParam_103401311064890">
            <param-name>servlet.class</param-name>
            <param-value>flashgateway.controller.GatewayServlet</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param id="InitParam_1034013110642x">
            <param-name>cfRootDir</param-name>
            <param-value>./WEB-INF/cfusion</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>gateway.configuration.file</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/gateway-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>whitelist.configuration.file</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/gateway-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>whitelist.parent.node</param-name>
            <param-value>gateway-config</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param id="InitParam_1034013110643a">
            <param-name>appServer</param-name>
            <param-value>J2EE</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>11</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet id="coldfusion_servlet_12">
        <servlet-name>CFFormGateway</servlet-name>
        <display-name>CFFormGateway</display-name>
        <description>Allows flash forms to connect to CFML and CFC templates.</description>
        <servlet-class>coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param id="InitParam_103401311064891">
            <param-name>servlet.class</param-name>
            <param-value>flashgateway.controller.GatewayServlet</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param id="InitParam_1034013110642y">
            <param-name>cfRootDir</param-name>
            <param-value>./WEB-INF/cfusion</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>gateway.configuration.file</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/cfform-gateway-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>whitelist.configuration.file</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/cfform-gateway-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>whitelist.parent.node</param-name>
            <param-value>gateway-config</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param id="InitParam_1034013110643b">
            <param-name>appServer</param-name>
            <param-value>J2EE</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>12</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <servlet id="coldfusion_servlet_3">
        <servlet-name>CfmServlet</servlet-name>
        <display-name>CFML Template Processor</display-name>
        <description>Compiles and executes CFML pages and tags</description>
        <servlet-class>coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param id="InitParam_1034013110656ert">
            <param-name>servlet.class</param-name>
            <param-value>coldfusion.CfmServlet</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>4</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet id="coldfusion_servlet_4">
        <servlet-name>GraphServlet</servlet-name>
        <display-name>GraphServlet</display-name>
        <description>Serves up graph data</description>
        <servlet-class>coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param id="InitParam_1034013110657xx">
            <param-name>servlet.class</param-name>
            <param-value>coldfusion.graph.GraphServlet</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet id="coldfusion_servlet_5">
        <servlet-name>CFCServlet</servlet-name>
        <display-name>CFC Processor</display-name>
        <description>Compiles and executes CF web components</description>
        <servlet-class>coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param id="InitParam_1034013110657ax">
            <param-name>servlet.class</param-name>
            <param-value>coldfusion.xml.rpc.CFCServlet</param-value>
       </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>10</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

        <!-- Used in calling OnServerStart, so this should be the last one to get initialized -->
        <servlet id="coldfusion_servlet_1001">
            <servlet-name>ServerCFCServlet</servlet-name>
            <display-name>OnServerStart Servlet</display-name>
            <description>Invokes OnServerStart</description>
            <servlet-class>coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param id="InitParam_1034013110613">
                <param-name>servlet.class</param-name>
                <param-value>coldfusion.cfc.ServerCFCServlet</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param id="InitParam_1034013110614">
                <param-name>cfRootDir</param-name>
                <param-value>./WEB-INF/cfusion</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1001</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <!-- begin REST -->
        <servlet id="coldfusion_servlet_6">
            <servlet-name>CFRestServlet</servlet-name>
            <display-name>Rest Processor</display-name>
            <description>Starts and configures rest web components</description>
            <servlet-class>coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param id="InitParam_1034013110657rs">
                <param-name>servlet.class</param-name>
                <param-value>coldfusion.rest.servlet.CFRestServlet</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
                <param-value>coldfusion.rest.servlet.CFUriConnegFilter;coldfusion.rest.servlet.CFRequestFilter</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
                <param-value>coldfusion.rest.servlet.CFResponseFilter</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>11</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <!-- end REST -->

    <!-- begin RDS -->
    <servlet id="coldfusion_servlet_8789">
        <servlet-name>RDSServlet</servlet-name>
        <display-name>RDS Servlet</display-name>
        <servlet-class>coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param id="InitParam_103401311065856789">
            <param-name>servlet.class</param-name>
            <param-value>coldfusion.rds.RdsFrontEndServlet</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <!-- end RDS -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CFFileServlet</servlet-name>
        <display-name>Serves files for cfpresentation,cfreport,captcha etc</display-name>
        <servlet-class>coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>servlet.class</param-name>
            <param-value>coldfusion.util.CFFileServlet</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

     <!-- WSRP producer servlet.. -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>WSRPProducer</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>servlet.class</param-name>
            <param-value>org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>101</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>


    <!-- Flash Remoting/Flex mapping -->
    <servlet-mapping id="coldfusion_mapping_0">
        <servlet-name>MessageBrokerServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/flex2gateway/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- start flex2
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FlexMxmlServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.mxml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FlexInternalServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/flex-internal/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>    
    end flex2 -->

    <servlet-mapping id="coldfusion_mapping_1">
        <servlet-name>FlashGateway</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/flashservices/gateway/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping id="coldfusion_mapping_2">
        <servlet-name>GraphServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/CFIDE/GraphData</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping id="coldfusion_mapping_3">
        <servlet-name>CfmServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.cfm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping id="coldfusion_mapping_4">
        <servlet-name>CFCServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.cfc</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping id="coldfusion_mapping_5">
        <servlet-name>CfmServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.cfml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- Please leave these .cfm/* mappings in.
          They are included to support Search Engine Safe (SES) URL types. 
    -->
    <!-- begin SES -->
    <servlet-mapping id="coldfusion_mapping_6">
        <servlet-name>CfmServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.cfml/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping id="coldfusion_mapping_7">
        <servlet-name>CfmServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.cfm/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping id="coldfusion_mapping_8">
        <servlet-name>CFCServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.cfc/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- end SES -->
    <!-- begin RDS -->
    <servlet-mapping id="coldfusion_mapping_9">
        <servlet-name>RDSServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/CFIDE/main/ide.cfm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- end RDS -->
    <servlet-mapping id="coldfusion_mapping_10">
        <servlet-name>CFCServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jws</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping id="coldfusion_mapping_11">
        <servlet-name>GraphServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/CFIDE/GraphData.cfm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping id="coldfusion_mapping_12">
        <servlet-name>CFCServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.cfr</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping id="coldfusion_mapping_13">
        <servlet-name>CFFormGateway</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/CFFormGateway/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping id="coldfusion_mapping_14">
        <servlet-name>CFFileServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/CFFileServlet/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping id="coldfusion_mapping_15">
        <servlet-name>CFRestServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CFForbiddenServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.hbmxml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- start flash form settings -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CFInternalServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/cfform-internal/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CFSwfServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.cfswf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CFForbiddenServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.as</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CFForbiddenServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.sws</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CFForbiddenServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.swc</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!-- end flash form settings -->

   <!--  WSRP producer servlet mapping.. -->
   <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>WSRPProducer</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/WSRPProducer/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>



    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <distributable/>

    <welcome-file-list id="WelcomeFileList_1034013110672">
        <welcome-file>index.cfm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>


    <!-- start flex2
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>FlexTagLib</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/lib/cf-bootstrap-for-flex.jar</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
    end flex2 -->

</web-app>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732/invalid-url-pattern-servlet-mapping-in-tomcat-6-0), the pattern isn't legal in the servlet spec: You can either start or end with a * but not use more than one. JRun hapened to support this style of mapping but tomcat does not. Railo has the same problem

[Adobe have modified their version of Tomcat](http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/what-s-the-deal-with-tomcat-in-coldfusion-10) in order to support those patterns.

All the examples I can find suggest adding extra servlet mappings to particular files such as foo/index.cfm/* which is fine if you can list all your pages that use SES style parameters, but not much use if you use them all over the place.

Other options I can think of are to use the [Tuckey rewrite filter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) to map your SES URLs to regular URL parameters.

Althernatively, you could change to a Tomcat7 instance and modify your web.xml to refer to the servlet spec version 3 which tomcat7 supports. Servlet 3 spec allows regular expressions in the servlet mappings, which should allow you to properly support SES mappings.

Do post to let us know how you get on.

Comment: Thank you @barnyr. Traveling this week but I'll try your recommendations as soon as possible and post back.

Comment: Have not forgotten about this thread... We've solved these issues but many and more have appeared. Will report back. Thanks.